# Super privilege on MySQL Database hosted under Hostinger

Tags: mysql

I tried granting super privilege to MySQL, but it doesn't work. My max_user_connections is set to 15 and I want to increase it.

```
SQL query:

GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO u369615699_jg@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234567899'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user 'u369615699_jg'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I don't know what else to do, as I don't have privileges to change it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In a shared hosting environment, serverwide settings usually can't be changed by users. Sometimes the support might do it, but I doubt they will change this setting. Maybe upgrading your hosting plan helps, but you should ask that beforehand. The setting just limits the number of connections per login, so if you can add more db users, you can use their connections too (although I am not sure if your hoster likes or forbids/bans that). You should also make sure it's not a problem on your end (e.g. that you do not close your connections (fast enough)), or maybe you can use connection sharing.